# Display weekday on x axis instead of date on Grafana

Tags: graph, grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

Hi is there a way to display the day of the week on a Grafana plot eg Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday on the x axis instead of the date eg 05/27, 05/28, 05/29 etc?

Comment: It seems you may have to change some things to achieve this. Did you look at this https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6373?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible, but it depends on your Grafana version.
https://grafana.com/blog/2020/09/23/grafana-v7.2-released-with-custom-date-formats-new-transforms-and-overrides/#new=date-formatting-options-added

Possible formats -> https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/